# Word for buying custom made artwork

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that is used when someone talks about ordering something custom-made. I've heard it mostly associated with buying art, like paintings only made for the buyer.

I've thought about *order*, *procure*, *purchase*, but they're not quite it.

Comment: Probably ***commission***? My worry is “custom-made” covers a lot of territory, and for example one does not *commission* a bespoke business suit. But one does *commission* artwork.

Comment: @DanBron That's exactly it! I can never remember it. Put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I’m too lazy for that ;) But SE allows you to self-answer to to accept that answer. I’ll upvote you.

Comment: @DanBron Alright, thanks. You saved my tonight's sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **Dan Bron** pointed out, the word is *commission*.

> [Commission](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commission): An order for something, especially a work of art, to
>   be produced specially.

Wikipedia has a page for it.

> [Commission (art)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_(art)): In art, a commission is the act of requesting the creation of a piece, often on behalf of another.

*Example: In ancient Rome, large architectural projects were commissioned as symbols of imperial glory.*